# How can I pass ssh password along with the username and hostname from browser i.e. Chrome/Safari to terminal app on mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssh, terminal, safari

I want to open a SSH link into the terminal without prompting user to enter the password?
I know terminal app on mac supports custom-uri scheme of ssh to launch terminal from browser. I'm able to pass username and hostname but unable to find any way to pass password.